# How to flush github object messages in tree view with updated history?

Tags: git, github, history

This is a new repos I was filling with the initial content, no other collabs involved yet.

I made some mistakes in the commit messages in my git repo; I noticed this after I pushed it to gihub, as it showed up as note after every file or folder involved in the file browser.

--

So I rewrote the history by resetting my local index a few steps back, and carefully committing all files with the correct messages. Then I force-pushed it over my branch on github.

In the history in my local git I see the nice messages. Then I check the history on github and it also shows the nice messages.

But in the tree view on the github website (eg: the standard file/directory list) each file and directory still shows the ugly messages. The bad commits touched most files that are in there, so it shows pretty much for every directory and file, even files unlikely to ever change, like the LICENCE file).

This message is nowhere to be found in my local data. So github is showing data that (afaick) doesn't even exists in my repos anymore.

--

I even deleted the branch from the github repos and pushed my local one, and still it shows the old messages in all the relevant tree views.

Then I went as far as using the Github API (I use this for another project) and try accessing related objects and I simply cannot product the offending messages. They do not exists in that branch (or any other)

But still when you go the repos in your browser every file you see is tagged with this 'ghost' message.

What is going on here?

Does git have more places for messages then just the commits? It it attached to like trees or blobs?

Do I have to drop the whole repos to purge this?

(note: I do not ask if this is a good idea or not: but how to get rid of these messages).

(also I have a question pending at Github but answers takes days sometimes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support staff was quick today, it turned out this is a web infrastructure cache that can take a little time to sync. It definitely should be same as in the git data history after a while.

So we learn.